# Cannot assign to read only property while adding new item on array inside transformResponse

Tags: angularjs

JSON:

```
[{"name":"John"},{"name":"Jim"}]
```

Error:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'age' of [ at transformResponse (angular.js?compile=false:9224) at processQueue (angular.js?compile=false:12914)
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myservice', [])
     .factory("demoService", function ($http,rootUrl) {
            return {
                getDashboardData: function () {
                    return $http({
                        url: rootUrl + '/api/mainpage',
                        method: 'GET',
                        transformResponse: function (data) {
                            var currentDate = new Date();

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var row = data[i];
                                row["age"] = 35;
                            }
                            return data;
                      }
                });
            }
      }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code, however, could you do a `console.log` for `data` in `transformResponse` and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data needs to be deserialized before you can manipulate it.  When you specify an additional transformResponse, the data object passed to it has not been through Angular's default transformResponse yet, so it hasn't been parsed to JSON yet. I usually parse the JSON as the first step in my transformResponse like: data = JSON.parse(data);

```
angular.module('myservice', [])
 .factory("demoService", function ($http,rootUrl) {
        return {
            getDashboardData: function () {
                return $http({
                    url: rootUrl + '/api/mainpage',
                    method: 'GET',
                    transformResponse: function (data) {
                        // parse data as JSON first
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        var currentDate = new Date();

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var row = data[i];
                            row["age"] = 35;
                        }
                        return data;
                  }
            });
        }
  }
```

});